# Mockito captor for Int in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I want to capture and verify an Int (or other primitive) parameter passed to a Kotlin function in my unit test. I did some search and could not find how to create the captor in the code below. Any suggestion?

```
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.mock
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.times
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.verify
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor

open class ClassUnderTest {  // Must be open (not final) to mock
    open fun print(a: Int) {  // Must be open (not final) to mock
        println("ClassUnderTest: $a")
    }
}

class CaptorTest {
    @Test
    fun testCaptor() {
        val testObject = mock<ClassUnderTest>()

        testObject.print(12)
        testObject.print(34)

        val captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer::class.java) // error: captor.capture is Integer, not Int
//        val captor = ArgumentCaptor<Int>()  // error: private constructor
        verify(testObject, times(2)).print(captor.capture())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.argumentCaptor` is the way to go. The corrected and complete example is as follows.

```
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.argumentCaptor
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.mock
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.times
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.verify
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

open class ClassUnderTest {  // Must be open (not final) to mock
    open fun print(a: Int) {  // Must be open (not final) to mock
        println("ClassUnderTest: $a")
    }
}

class CaptorTest {
    @Test
    fun testCaptor() {
        val testObject = mock<ClassUnderTest>()

        testObject.print(12)
        testObject.print(34)

//        val captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer::class.java) // error: captor.capture is Integer, not Int
//        val captor = ArgumentCaptor<Int>()  // error: private constructor
        val captor = argumentCaptor<Int>()
        verify(testObject, times(2)).print(captor.capture())
        assertEquals(12, captor.firstValue)
        assertEquals(34, captor.secondValue)
    }
}
```